# Multiple input fields with the same name C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, macos, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using VS for Mac, .NET Core 2.0, MVC.

I'm trying to make a form that accepts multiple input parameters for text under the same name. 
My view contains the following:

```
<div>
     <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" type="email"/>
     <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" type="email"/>
     <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" type="email"/>
     <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" type="email"/>
<div>
```

This gives me errors, I've read something about naming the inputs Email[] but I cannot make it work.

How do I put my view in order, and how do I receive the email addresses later in the controller?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand. How did you resolved this?

Answer (score 2):

`Email[]` is a class (assuming from your notation - if you were talking about the action declaration), the input is most likely just a string.

So change the action parameter to `string[] Email`.

ASP.NET Core model binder will treat multiple equally named parameters as array, so either `Email` or `Email[]` should work in your View.

HTML has no notion of "arrays", from  HTML point of view `Email[]` is just a normal name as `Email`. It only depends on the backend technology how this naming conventions will be interpreted.

i.e. PHP will treat multiple `Email` values (i.e. `Email=abc@xyz&Email=def@ghx`) as one single value (using the first or last parameter), whereas ASP.NET & ASP.NET Core interpret it as array.

Comment: Hi Tseng, thanks for your reply. 

It's good to know that HTML makes no distinction between types; Email[] is the same as Email.

It's also good to know that the ASP.NET Core model binder will treat multiple equally named parameters as array. That helps me ahead. 

In my code, Email is a string property of my model, but I have to change this to an array of strings, correct?

Still, if I now try get access to the array in the controller via model binding I find that Email = null..

Comment: Is there a code example?